# How to obtain the same lenght string encoding with Blowfish+Hex

Tags: blowfish

We're trying to encode several input strings with the same length (32) applying Blowfish + Hex encoding.
The problem is that not always the final coded strings have the same length as we expect (32 length strings).
Below you find the code used. Please, can you help to suggest what's wrong?

```
public static String encrypt(String clear, String key)
{                          
    try
    {
        Security.setProperty("crypto.policy", "unlimited");
        byte [] keyBytes = key.getBytes("ASCII");//toByteArray(key);
        filelogger.info("Key coded in bytes "+keyBytes);
        SecretKeySpec skey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "Blowfish");
        byte [] clearBytes = clear.getBytes();//toByteArray(clear);
        filelogger.info("Input string coded in bytes "+clearBytes);
        Cipher ci = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");                            
        ci.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skey);

        // encrypt the clear bytes value
        byte[] encoded = ci.doFinal(clearBytes);
        filelogger.info("Blowfish output "+encoded);

        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encoded);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        filelogger.error("Error while encrypting: " + e.toString());
        logger.error("Error while encrypting: " + e.toString());

        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(new byte[0]);
    }
}
```

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

We have solved using the following solution:

1. Passing the option "Blowfish/ECB/NoPadding" to the getInstance function.

   public byte[] encryptBlowfishECBNopadding(byte[] key, byte[] dati) {
   byte[] output = null;
   try {
      SecretKeySpec KS = new SecretKeySpec(key, "Blowfish");
      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/ECB/NoPadding");
      cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, KS);
   output = cipher.doFinal(dati);
   return output;
   } catch (Exception ee) {
   logger.error(ee.getMessage());
   filelogger.error(ee.toString());
   return new byte[0];
   }
   }
2. Encoding the result of the method as below:

   byte[] encryptresult=encryptBlowfishECBNopadding(toByteArray(decriptedki),toByteArray(criptokeyhlr.getKeydata()));
   String stringencriptedki=Hex.encodeHexString(encryptresult).toUpperCase();

In this manner every output string has the same length.

Thanks to all for the support!